# how to split a string using a specific character?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='test'>abc+defg+323+gh2+ab3</div>
```

js

```
var a = $('#test').html();
```

Is it possible the folowing:

```
var b = content of a before the first plus sign
var c = content of a between the first and the second plus sign
var d = content of a between the second and the third plus sign
var e = content of a between the third and the fourth plus sign
```

Plus sign is always unique, i.e. it is used just as separator, not in the string itself.

Comment: yes, use the `split` function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: OK. Either you write the properly answer yourself and accept it, or you delete the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily solved by searching the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var vals = a.split('+'); //yields an array of whats between the +'s

var b = vals[0], c=vals[1], d=vals[2], e=vals[2];
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = $('#test').html();
var array = a.split('+');
var b= array[0];
var c= array[1]; ...
```